# resampling matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, permutation

I have generated an observed matrix, here is the code:

```
obs.matrix <- matrix(c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10)),nrow=10,ncol=2)
```

and now I want to get 3000 permuted dataset, in each dataset, there should be 10's 1 and 10's 2 but they can be in different columns.

I don't know how to do the rest.
I have tried but failed.

```
x =obs.matrix
theta = function(resample){sample(c(1,2),replace = T)}
result <- bootstrap::bootstrap(x,3000,theta)
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: `t(sapply(1:10, function(ign) sample(1:2)))`?

Comment: `replicate(3000, sample(rep(1:2, 10)))` From each sample you can form a 10*2-matrix.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for answer but how can I replicate for 3000 times?

Comment: Use `replicate(3000, ...)`, as the other comments are suggesting.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you so much!